# Why my fragment is not destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to replace `Fragment` A by a `Fragment` B but the `onDestroy()` method is not called on the `Fragment` B.

Broadcast receivers are unregistered and threads are killed before replacing the fragment.

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transac = manager.beginTransaction();
transac.replace(R.id.content_fragment_A, fragmentB, myTAG);
transac.commit();
```

Why is my `Fragment` A not destroyed ?

Comment: How do you know is not getting destroyed?

Comment: A Log is displayed is the onDestroy() method when it is destroyed. Here not. Only when I kill manually the app.

Comment: Does it eventually get destroyed, or the log message never shows?

Comment: The log is diplayed when I kill manually the app so...

Comment: I meant in the case where you do not kill it manually. It never shows?

Comment: Yes, when use back press for example but never I use replace fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Fragment`'s `onDestroy()` is called when the `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` is called. In your scenario you are just replacing `Fragments` but you didn't destroy your `Activity` yet. If you want to check on this try to destroy your `Activity` after you replace your `Fragment`, both `fragmentA` and `fragmentB` `onDestroy()` should be called.

Answer (score 2):

I would look more into the fragment activity lifcycle

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

[image: The lifecycle of a fragment (while its activity is running)]

When are adding the new fragment to an existing ViewGroup, for replace function:

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

and a remove

> Remove an existing fragment. If it was added to a container, its view
>   is also removed from that container.

From this terminology, I assume that onDestroyView() is being called and not necessary onDestory right away.